# $|\sin^2x-\sin^2y|\le K|x-y|$ find K

Tags: calculus

Find the smallest positive number K for which following inequality

$$|\sin^2x-\sin^2y|\le K|x-y|$$

Holds for all x and y

1.2

2.1

3.$\pi$/2

4. No value of K is possible

My attempt:
the way inequality is, it reminds me of lagrange mean value theorm.so k shud be 1, I think. I need suggestion here thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Apply the mean value theorem to $f(x)=\sin^2x$.
$$
f'(x)=2\sin x\cos x=\sin(2\,x).
$$

Comment: Ya thats how I thought about it. if there was no less than in the inequality k would be 1

Comment: Sir plz confirm if k is 1 correct?

Comment: How large can $|\sin(2\,x)|$ be?

Comment: it can be atmost 1